# Water moving up in a pot of soil

Tags: water

Assume I have a pot of dry soil. Now I add water to the bottom of the pot. What happens is that water will move up the soil. No more dry soil in the pot.

I am not sure what precisely is going on here, I guess it has something to do with the dry soil attracting water.

My question is what exactly is going on, what are the governing physical principles here? Given that somebody explains this in detail, it should also be possible to influence that behavior by adding/removing some ingredients of a "typical" soil (or changing its density by compressing it, for example).

Comment: [Capillarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillarity).

Comment: @SebastianRiese hm, I though that would apply to plants itself or some other structures which are somewhat like small tubes/fibers. Soil seemed to be too "unstructured" to me...?

Comment: See the section about porous materials in the article. It is enough that there are small connected cavities and the material is wetting. It does not matter whether the cavities are regularly shaped or not (although this does influence up to which height the water rises).